# No se me actualiza mis datos en mysql

Tags: php, sql, update

### Buen dia lo que intento hacer es que tengo una serie de registros los cuales llevan un NCliente,status junto con su tiempo y manejo dos tipos

Estatus1: Entrada, HoraE 12:00:00
Estatus2: Salida,  HoraS 1:00:00

ejemplo si una persona ingresa ala tienda se registra con una serie de datos se genera la HoraE y le asigno un status1= Entrada  entonces después cuando salga se registra una HoraS diferente y hago un update al estatus a Estatus2 =Salida y resto los tiempo y la guardo en otra columna donde sea igual al NCliente.

```
        $Estatus1 = "Entrada";

        $up = $con->prepare("UPDATE  Cliente SET HoraS=:HoraS where NCliente= '$NCliente'  and Estatus = '$Estatus1'");

        $up->bindparam(':HoraS', $dateNew);
        $result = $up->execute();
         if ($result === true) {
             
                
                $selectT = $con->prepare("UPDATE Cliente SET Promedio=HoraS-HoraE, Estatus=:Estatus where NCliente= '$NCliente'  and Estatus = '$Estatus1'");
                $Estatus2 = "salida";
                $selectT->bindparam(':Estatus', $Estatus2);
                $Promedio = $selectT->execute();
                 if ($Promedio === true) {
                    echo "Exitoso";
                 }else{
                     echo "algo ha fallado";
                 }        
    }
```

Todo me funciona ala primera Pero cuando esa misma regrese con el mismo NCliente ya no me actualiza al estatus2=Salida ni el promedio o sea no se hace la resta solo se ejecuta el update de arriba para actalizar la fecha de la HoraS.

Primera vez que ingresa

```
NCLiente| HoraE   | HoraS | Promedio | Estatus

5       | 12:00:00|-------| ----     | Entrada
```

Cuando va de salida

```
NCLiente| HoraE  | HoraS | Promedio | Estatus
5      | 12:00:00|1:00:00|    1     | Salida
```

Segunda vez que regresa

```
NCLiente| HoraE | HoraS | Promedio | Estatus
5      | 1:00:00|-------|   ----   | Entrada
```

Cuando va de salida

```
NCLiente| HoraE  | HoraS | Promedio | Estatus
5      | 1:00:00 |3:00:00|  ---     | Entrada
```

No se actualiza el estatus y ni el promedio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario hacerlo en dos partes, puedes actualizar varias columnas al mismo tiempo:

```
$sentenciaSalida = $con->prepare( "UPDATE Cliente
                                     SET HoraS = :HoraS
                                       , Promedio = HoraS-HoraE
                                       , Estatus = 'Salida'
                                     WHERE NCliente = :NCliente
                                       AND Estatus = 'Entrada'
                                  "
                                );
$sentenciaSalida->bindParam( ':HoraS', $dateNew );
$sentenciaSalida->bindParam( ':NCliente', $NCliente );
$sentenciaSalida->execute();
```

Nota que puedes -y debes- vincular todos los parámetros que puedas en la sentencia preparada.

Comment: Hoo ok.Lo probaré cuando pueda.

Comment: Lo que se me hace raro es que en el localhost me funcionaba bien pero en el servidor ya no no se si tenga algo que ver qué anteriormente ese registro ya tenía el estatus de salida y ahora que quiero hacer lo mismo con el mismo NCliente ya no se actualiza por qué en el pasado registro ya tenía ese estatus de SALIDA